# How Would I Display the Score in this Simple Game?

Tags: python, pygame

I've tried using the blit function to paste it to the surface but that didn't work because I couldn't use a surface as a source for the score as I did with the player, enemy, and food variables. I also tried using self.score = Score((75, 575)) but that didn't work because for some reason it said "self" wasn't defined. How can I display the score onto the screen?

```
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

WINDOWWIDTH = 1000
WINDOWHEIGHT = 700
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Avoid!")

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

player = pygame.Rect(500, 300, 40, 40)
playerImage = pygame.Surface((40, 40))

enemy = pygame.Rect(300, 400, 20, 20)
enemyImage = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
enemyImage.fill((RED))

food = pygame.Rect(300, 500 , 20, 20)
foodImage = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
foodImage.fill((GREEN))

moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVESPEED = 6

class Score(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """A sprite for the score."""

    def __init__(self, xy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.xy = xy  #save xy -- will center our rect on it when we change the score
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)  # load the default font, size 50
        self.color = (255, 165, 0)         # our font color in rgb
        self.score = 0  # start at zero
        self.reRender() # generate the image

    def update(self):
        pass

    def add(self, points):
        """Adds the given number of points to the score."""
        self.score += points
        self.reRender()
        if player.colliderect(food):
            return add

    def reset(self):
        """Resets the scores to zero."""
        self.score = 0
        self.reRender()

    def reRender(self):
        """Updates the score. Renders a new image and re-centers at the initial coordinates."""
        self.image = self.font.render("%d"%(self.score), True, self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.xy

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True

    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

    if moveDown and player.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
        player.top += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
        player.right +=MOVESPEED

    if player.colliderect(enemy):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    windowSurface.blit(playerImage, player)
    windowSurface.blit(enemyImage, enemy)
    windowSurface.blit(foodImage, food)

    score = Score((75, 575))

    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print() outputs text to stdout (aka the command line). I thought your problem was just with self and that you understand the part about pygame.

Here is a code block I found online that does what you are trying to do:

```
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
text = font.render("Pummel The Chimp, And Win $$$", 1, (10, 10, 10))
textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=background.get_width()/2)
background.blit(text, textpos)
```

Comment: But how would I make the text dynamic? Meaning how would I be able to change it if the player got a point?

Comment: font.render("The score of the game is: %d" % (my_score.score), 1, (10,10,10). Update it the way you normally would any sprite.

Comment: One way to do it would be to re-blit the text every time you update the score. So put the code that blits the text on screen in your Score.add() method.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't with blit or any other part of pygame; it is with your use of the self keyword. Self is a reference to an object's attributes. You do not call self.score outside of the Score class itself.

Instead, initialize a score object in the beginning of the game and add to the score as needed. This is how it should work:

```
# init Score object
my_score = Score((75, 575))
# add to score like this
my_score.add(5)
# access score attribute like this
# for simplicity, I print the value to the console
print my_score.score # not self.score!
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It still doesn't print the score on the screen. Are you sure "print" is the right way to display it?